# Integrating a Native Android Library into Expo/React Native Projec

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to integrate a [native Android SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-Proximity-SDK#how-to-use-it-in-your-app) into my Expo/React Native project. I know there is a tool called Expo Native Modules that allows this type of integration. My knowledge in Java/Kotlin is very limited, and I'm unable to find any documentation or example that specifically explains how to expose and integrate a native Android SDK into JavaScript code in Expo.